# I'm getting the error "The username you entered doesn't appear to belong to an account" in instagram-private-api

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, bots, instagram

I'm new to this library (https://npmjs.com/instagram-private-api). I've been trying for a while but still no success at logging in.

My code is:

```js
import { IgApiClient } from 'instagram-private-api';
import { config } from "dotenv";
export default class BotService {
  ig: IgApiClient;
  user: string;
  password: string;
  constructor() {
  config();
    this.user = process.env.USER;
    this.password = process.env.PASS;
    this.ig = new IgApiClient();
  }

  async login(){
    await this.ig.state.generateDevice(this.user);
    await this.ig.simulate.preLoginFlow();
    const loggedInAccount = await this.ig.account.login(this.user, this.password);
    await this.ig.simulate.postLoginFlow();
    console.log(loggedInAccount.full_name);
  }
  
}
```

Error:

```
    at Request.handleResponseError (C:\Users\minsiam\Downloads\instagrem\node_modules\instagram-private-api\src\core\request.ts:172:12)
    at Request.send (C:\Users\minsiam\Downloads\instagrem\node_modules\instagram-private-api\src\core\request.ts:83:24)
[ERROR] 12:47:35 IgResponseError: POST /api/v1/accounts/login/ - 400 Bad Request; The username you entered doesn't appear to belong to an account. Please check your username and try again.
```

The username is correct, tried directly putting it (without env) but it still didn't work.

Comment: The error message seems to be pretty clear `The username you entered doesn't appear to belong to an account. Please check your username and try again.`

Comment: Sorry, I missed that part. The username is correct. I even tried directly putting the username (without env), it didn't work. Sorry again for not mentioning it, I'll edit and add it. But yeah the username is correct so you know.

Comment: How do you know the username is correct? The error message seems to come from the server. The server should know whether the username is correct.

Comment: The username is 100% correct. If I go to instagram.com/theusername it works. I bet this is not the issue...

Comment: It's also copy pasted so no point.

Comment: Are you sure it's the same username? You usually need separate credentials for the API. Can you try to log in using the HTTP API using cURL or Postman?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure it is the same username. The library did not mention anything about separate credentials. How do I login using curl?

Comment: Do you have a link to the API documentation?

Comment: @jabaa you're being annoying. even I had the same error, after giving in the correct username. instagram's API is just designed like that. it usually gives me the error once I login too many times with the same proxy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Damn that library.
Tried for days, still no success. But I finally found a new library.
(https://www.npmjs.com/package/instauto) It seems to be working pretty well.
Maybe it was an issue of the old library? I contacted the owner and seems like he stopped working on it. It may be the library issue who knows.
But yeah the question is solved now, thanks!